# creating a menu from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so iv been trying to write a code that works like a menu creating program that :

1# take the input from user to define the number of products and there names

2# assign prices separately after taking products names from user

3# display the menu after its done

my problem with the code that i cant go to function 2 after function 1 is done ,the program just quite after first loop
indentation is wrong due to the editor here ,it just change my code position i don't know why

am a beginner in coding and python language
this is how my code is looking after many tries and researches

```
def functions():
maxlengh = input("how many products in your card ? : ")
maxlengh = int(maxlengh)
select_function = input("press 1 to add product names to the menu or 2 to assign prises : ")
select_function = int(select_function)
products = []
while select_function == 1 and len(products) != maxlengh :
    items = input("enter product name : ")
    items= items.split()
    products.append(items)
    if len(products) == maxlengh :
        select_function == 2
        prise = []
    while select_function ==2 and len(prise) != maxlengh :
        items = input("enter product prise : ")
        items = items.split()
        prise.append(items)
    menu = dict(zip(products,prise))
    print(menu  )
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue/problem with the code?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and fix the indentation of the code which is very important in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

> `dict`

Here is your code:

```
def functions():
    maxlengh = int(input("how many products in your card ? : "))
    products = [] #[{name:"name",price:"price",}]
   for num in range(maxlengh):
        product_name=input("inter product name: ")
        product_price=input("inter product price: ")
        product={"name":product_name,"price":product_price}
        products.append(product)
    print(products)
    return  products
```

functions()

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:
in Python, indents are very important, and some of yours were a little off. this *should* work. good luck!

```
def functions():
    max_length = int(input("how many products in your card ? : "))
    select_function = input("press 1 to add product names to the menu or 2 to assign prices : ")
    select_function = int(select_function)
    products = []
    while select_function == 1 and len(products) != max_length :
        items = input("enter product name : ")
        items = items.split()
        products.append(items)
        if len(products) == max_length :
            select_function == 2
            price = []
            while select_function ==2 and len(price) != max_length :
                items = input("enter product price : ")
                items = items.split()
                price.append(items)
    menu = dict(zip(products,price))
    print(menu)
```